# What encoding and line-feeds should I use in my TeX files to ensure portability?

Tags: editors, tools, input-encodings

In many of the editors and tools I use, I'm given the option to choose an "encoding" as well as a choice among "new lines". For example, in BBEdit, I am given the following for encoding

[image]

and this

[image]

for new lines.

Are there settings for these that are more likely to ensure portability across platforms and tools? Are there corresponding settings or options in LaTeX code that need to match the choices made here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the file format, you can probably ignore the `Classic Mac (CR)` option as these days, Mac use the `Unix (LF)` line ending. The picky one will be windows on this one as although  some editors will support Unix line ending, be default, users will probably have issues with such files. So for that reason I would use the `Windows (CRLF)` option as Unix/Linux/OS X will also be able to handle these files without any problems. (I am a unix user with very few dealings with windows so my preconceptions may be wrong regarding this OS and maybe things have changed in this regard.)

This I think will be an issue only for viewing the source or editing. Compilation should not be a problem whichever option you choose.

Regarding the file encoding, I think UTF-8 is pretty standard these days and probably the recommended option. Make sure you either use the correct `inputenc` when using latex/pdflatex or use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX which assume that the input file is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Good editors under Windows should be able to interpret files with `LF` line ending (and in the past I've had problems with `CRLF` line endings). I'd go with `LF`, but your advice is just as good, I believe.

Comment: @egreg: And it sounds like, if I avoid Windows altogether LF should be fine.

Comment: I think what @egreg is saying is that unless you use notepad to edit your files, `LF` will also be fine on Windows. If you use BBEdit under OS X, UltraEdit under Windows should be very familiar.